# Taxonomy Custom field image is not showing

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I want to show taxonomy custom field images on loop on the home page
"developers" is taxonomy name
and "developer_logo" is image field slug
I used that code only name is showing but image is not showing

```
 <?php      
        $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'developers', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
        $image = get_field('developer_logo');
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
        
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="product product-zoom product--card">
                    <div class="product__thumbnail">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-desc">
                        <h4 class="text-center mb-2"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        
        <?php
        endforeach
        ?>
```

[image]
[image]

[image: This is how it is showing]

I just want to show the images of taxonomy custom field

Answer (score 0):

```
**In the below code, i have added the term Id as second parameter in get_field() function to get image URL & replaced the $image variable from outside of loop to inside the foreach loop.** 
        
        <?php
       $terms = get_terms(array(
          'taxonomy' => 'developers',
          'hide_empty' => false
       ));
       foreach ($terms as $term) {
          $image = get_field('developer_logo', $term->id); ?>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
             <div class="product product-zoom product--card">
                <div class="product__thumbnail">
                   <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $term->name;?>">
                </div>
                <div class="product-desc">
                   <h4 class="text-center mb-2"><?php echo $term->name;?></h4>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>  
          <?php
          }
    ?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In the code, i have added the term Id as second parameter in get_field() function to get image URL & replaced the $image variable from outside of loop to inside the foreach loop.